# SocketStream not executing anything from a newly added JS file in client

Tags: javascript, socketstream

I am doing this to load all JS files in `app` folder

```
ss.client.define('main', {
  view: 'app.jade',
  css:  [
    'libs/reset.css',
    'app.styl'
  ],
  code: [
    'libs/jquery-2.1.0.min.js',
    'libs/angular-1.2.10.min.js',
    'libs/lodash-2.4.1.min.js',
    'app'
  ],
  tmpl: '*'
});
```

There are 3 files in `app`, 2 that came with the default project and 1 that I added. The first 2 work fine, but the one I added does not get executed!

The funny thing is that when there are errors in that file, I set them in the Chrome console, but no function gets executed or variable added to the page.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

It will need access to the window variable/global-object.

Therefore you need to `require` it from your entry file. Typically this means having the lodash code file in your actual code (/client/code/[...]) directory.  I.e. you wouldn't put it in your libs folder, but in your main app folder, although you can make another libs folder there.

This is what I've always had to do in order to require --for example-- bootstrapJS.  It defies the organisation of the client side as they set it up, but it's the way things need to be done for stuff like this.

An alternative is to require it remotely (from CDN) from your main app.jade view file.

`script(src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js")`